# Uploaded images stored in AWS S3 not showing at Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, railstutorial.org

My Twitter-like application, with capability of posting messages and uploading images, is working well in my development environment.

I configured my application to use cloud storage in production as suggested in the Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial's '[Image upload in production](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-image_upload_in_production)' section, creating an AWS account, a bucket and a IAM user at Amazon Web Services.

However my Heroku application does not show my uploaded images.
What it shows is just the name of the uploaded image below the message, as if it were part of the message.

AWS S3 service looks well configured: I granted my IAM user (linked to my application) full access to all S3 services, and in my AWS console I can see the uploaded images and also have a preview of them.

What I do not understand is why at Heroku those images are not rendered.
My bucket's name is 34 characters long and has three periods (.), which is not the ideal format that Heroku suggests in [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3). However images, as I said, are correctly put in the bucket.

I also have taken for granted that Heroku comes with an installation of ImageMagick: is that so?

Do you have any idea why am I experiencing this issue?
Can the bucket's name have anything to do with it?

Comment: Can the bucket's name have anything to do with it? - yes. Have you got multiple periods in the name of your bucket?

Comment: Yes, I have got three periods, but not consecutive. The format is 'my.bucket-name.at.aws'

Comment: You should definitely try renaming without the periods

Comment: Many thanks, it was the bucket's name's format that, although supported by AWS S3, it was not compatible with Heroku.

Comment: Nice one! It was probably to do with Heroku getting hung up on the mulitple subdomains of the bucket etc.